# how to convert std::vector<float> to a tensor without copy in tensorflow in c++?

Tags: tensorflow

In c++, a multidimensional matrix is stored in `std::vector<float>`. I need to use it in tensorflow, which uses tensors.  The conversion from a `std::vector` to a tensor seems not obvious. There is a c_api which convert a vector to a `TF_Tensor` instead of `Tensor`. `std::copy` also works, but I want to perform a conversion without copy.

Comment: I suspect there's no convenient way to do it because TensorFlow has ownership of storage. Tensor could be could be physically located on a GPU, or it could be memory mapped to a file on disk.

Comment: @anteagle - did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow now has a way to do this in the C++ API by providing your own [`tensorflow::TensorBuffer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor-buffer#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_buffer_1ade0441d867aabc7d8c4f4a553d1e5fd3) and using the [following constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_1ac57b0c5223af0068c3de94e0f9fdba2c):

```
#include <tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h>
...
tensorflow::Tensor(tensorflow::DataType type, const TensorShape & shape, TensorBuffer *buf)
```

Since `tensorflow::TensorBuffer` is an abstract class, you'll need to subclass it and implement a few methods yourself (that said, it's fairly easy to do). One thing to note: notice how we have `OwnsMemory()` returning `false`. If you want to use manual memory management (malloc/free or new/delete), you can set this to true and then override the destructor yourself. That said, since you're using a `vector` I'd just set it to `false` and take care to not have the buffer go out of scope. When it does, `vector` will free its own internal memory anyways.

eg;

```cpp
class MyBuffer: public tensorflow::TensorBuffer {
    std::size_t len_;
  public:
    MyBuffer(void* data, std::size_t len): len_(len), tensorflow::TensorBuffer(data){}
    //returns how many bytes we have in our buffer
    std::size_t size() const override {return len_;};
    //needed so TF knows this isn't a child of some other buffer
    TensorBuffer* root_buffer() override { return this; }
    // Not actually sure why we need this, but it lets TF know where the memory for this tensor came from
    void FillAllocationDescription(tensorflow::AllocationDescription* proto) const override{};
    // A value of false indicates this TensorBuffer does not own the underlying data
    bool OwnsMemory() const override { return false; }
}
```

Then, you just need to provide the correct `tensorflow::DataType` (eg; `tensorflow::DT_FLOAT32`) and a `tensorflow::TensorShape` (you can just instantiate it and add each dimension using `<TensorShape>.addDim(<the dimension>)`. You could modify the above by storing the `std::vector` inside and then exposing the contents by using `.data()` and a `void*` cast to make a constructor for `MyBuffer` that takes in a vector. Or you could just do that yourself outside of `MyBuffer`.

Comment: You can't initialize members before the base class. You'll need to introduce an additional class that initializes the data and inherit from it before `TensorBuffer`.