# most efficient way to create tensorflow::tensor from std::vector

Tags: c++, tensorflow

So my question is to know if there is a way to pass directly the values from a `vector` (but we could also think about `array`) to a `tensorflow::tensor`?

The only way I know is to copy each value one by one.

**Example (2D Vector)**:

```
tensorflow::Tensor input(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({50, 20})); 
auto input_map = input.tensor<float, 2>();


for (int b = 0; b < 50; b++) {
  for (int c = 0; c < 20; c++) {
    input_map(b, c) = (vector_name)[b][c];
  }
}
```

Is there more convenient ways to do it?

For example `array` to `vector`:

```
int x[3] = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v(x, x + sizeof x / sizeof x[0]);
```

Comment: As a  aside, what leads you to believe that your array to vector snippet isnt copying anything? By "efficient" do you mean performance, or do you mean convenience?

Comment: I look mainly for performance. I though that this way the vector take the memory used by the array, but I am maybe wrong. Or for example the opposite action: int* pv = &v[0];   (create array from vector, for this one I am sure that it does not copy). But if there is something more convenient too I would be interested to see.

Comment: int* pv=&v[0] doesn't create an array. It assigns the current address of the vectors first element to a pointer (and pv may very well become invalid if you do something that resizes the vector, btw). And no, that vector constructor does not create a view of the array. It just copies the elements.

Comment: So I suppose nothing more efficient then?
In that case something more convenient?

Comment: There is this constructor Tensor::Tensor(Allocator* a, DataType type, const TensorShape& shape). But I do not see what (Allocator* a) ca be.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037962/how-to-convert-stdvectorfloat-to-a-tensor-without-copy-in-tensorflow-in-c

Answer (score 6):

how about this?
`std::copy_n(vec.begin(), vec.size(), input.flat<float>().data())`

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried `tf.convert_to_tensor`? Maybe something like `tf.convert_to_tensor(value, as_ref=True)`

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#convert_to_tensor

Comment: I am afraid it only apply to the python api, I am  talking about c++. I checked and did not find about convert_to_tensor in c++.