# Is there a clean way to create 3d tensors for feeding Tensorflow prediction in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I've built a model in Python where each input tensor has the shape (4, 6, 13). I want to run predictions with the model in C++.

I'd like to write a function that takes as input data in a C++ three-dimensional array:

`float input[4][6][13];`

and produces a `Tensor` with shape `TensorShape({4,6,13})`.

It seems `Eigen3` does not have support for 3d arrays. I see that `Tensorflow::Input::Initializer` can initialize a 3d tensor from an initializer list, but I have dynamic data, not compile-time constants.

After searching for a solution I am about to conclude that I should change my model to expect a flattened vector of length 4x6x13=312, and then reshape it as the first step, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: When it's about inferring the array's dimensions (i.e., the 4,6, and 13), it becomes tedious. As long as you know these sizes, however, it's almost trivial -- just define your tensor and assign it. So what exactly are you aiming for? Or, asked differently, is the function supposed to take the sizes as parameter as well, or only the array itself?

Comment: @davidhigh the dimensions are known constants. I'm glad to hear the implementation will then be trivial. But does it come down to writing a three-level nested loop to copy the values one by one? And what is the API to poke values into a rank 3 tensor? I see the methods `.flat()` and `.matrix()` for 1d and 2d access, but I don't see any 3d accessors.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something  as simple as what you said: set up the tensor with the respective shape (4,6,13), then use three loops to fill it via `operator()(int,int,int)`. By looking at the code, there seem to be also more elaborate  ways to do the assignment (there is e.g. a class TensorAssign.h).

Comment: pardon me but could you please write down the brute force method on writing/accessing the elements in a 3D tensor?

Comment: @user3085931: see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support#Using_the_Tensor_module), for example. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Thanks. BTW: That didn't run on my machine, it was working with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737304/most-efficient-way-to-create-tensorflowtensor-from-stdvector